# Make Nagios stack alarms when no connectivity to HP OVO

Tags: monitoring, nagios, snmp, system-monitoring, net-snmp

I'm implementing a small Nagios instance on a dedicated laptop to monitor some telcom devices.
The alarms have to be sent via our customer's reporting tool (like HP OpenView) via SNMP Traps. Nothing fancy here.

However, the subsystem is mobile and thus, does not always have connectivity to report alarms. We rely on a 3G modem to provide this connectivity (when available) for reporting.

**Is there any mean to make Nagios "stack" alarms when no connectivity to the Monitoring Tool**, so that it can deliver the last state of the alarms as soon as the connectivity is restored ?

I've though at first to a "man-in-the-middle" program that would make the bridge between Nagios and the monitoring tool and handles the traps. It would take all the snmp traps from Nagios, and if no connectivity available, stak them to then deliver the last traps...

But I don't know if such thing exists and as far as I've searched, I found nothing...

Comment: After a small serach, a lead could be to make Nagios send traps to a Perl program. This programm would then check the connectivity, and decide wether send the trap or stack it up unti connection is restored... But still investigating...